# groupby agg using a date offset or similar

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Sample of dataset below

Trying to create a groupby that will give me the number of months that I specify eg last 12 months, last 36 months etc.

My groupby that rolls up my whole dataset for each 'client' is below. rolled_ret is just a custom function that geometrically links whatever performance array it gets, we can pretend is is sum()

```
df_client_perf = df_perf.groupby(df_perf.CLIENT_NAME)['GROUP_PERFORMANCE'].agg(Client_Return = rolled_ret)
```

If I put .rolling(12) I can take the most recent entry to get the previous 12 months but there is obviously a better way to do this.

Worth saying that the period column is a monthly period datetime type using to_period

thanks in advance

```
PERIOD,CLIENT_NAME,GROUP_PERFORMANCE
2020-03,client1,0.104
2020-04,client1,0.004
2020-05,client1,0.23
2020-06,client1,0.113
2020-03,client2,0.0023
2020-04,client2,0.03
2020-05,client2,0.15
2020-06,client2,0.143
```

lets say for example that I wanted to do a groupby to SUM the latest three months of data, my expected output of the above would be

```
client1,0.347
client2,0.323
```

also - I would like a way to return nan if the dataset is missing the minimum number of periods, as you can do with the rolling function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer.

I've used a DatetimeIndex because the method `last` does not work with period. First I sort values based on the `PERIOD` column, then I set it as Index to keep only the last 3 months (or whatever you provide), then I do the groupby the same way as you.

```py
df['PERIOD'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PERIOD'])

(df.sort_values(by='PERIOD')
    .set_index('PERIOD')
    .last('3M')
    .groupby('CLIENT_NAME')
    .GROUP_PERFORMANCE
    .sum())

# Result
CLIENT_NAME GROUP_PERFORMANCE
client1     0.347
client2     0.323
```

Comment: thank you. i wasn't aware of the last function, that will work. I'll create a datetime column in the df. I see that there is a .first which solves a similar problem I'm about to have... thanks again pal

Any idea how to reject any CLIENT_NAME that doesn't have 3 periods / specified number of periods, or return nan?